# How can I get the post parameter value from the HttpErrorHandler part when an error occurs in scala playframework?

Tags: scala, playframework

I am in the introductory stage of Scala.

playframework version is 2.8.2

(1)
As the following, api is requested for the post method by including parameters in json format.

[image]

(2) If an error occurs, in the code of ErrorHandler.scala below

def onDevServerError function is executed and the result is returned in Json format as shown below.

- ErrorHandler.scala
  [image]
- Result return
  [image]

That's the problem here.

Before I return the result for the error,

I need to perform some action by fetching the values ​​for the post parameters sent when calling the api.
(i need groupId and jobId value)

how....???

I googled a lot, but I can't find the answer.

Please help me.

03-17  inject controllercomponents doesn't work
[image]

[image]

Maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: What kind of parameters you need: body, headers, query?

Comment: i need body parameters

Comment: Have you tried answer below?

Comment: Ok, my bad - I've edited answer. Could you try inject PlayBodyParsers instead of ControllerComponents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to inject `play.api.mvc.PlayBodyParsers` into your handler, like

```
class ErrorHandler @Inject(..., parsers: PlayBodyParsers) extends ...
```

then declare two fields which you need for parsing:

```
implicit val materializer = Materializer(ActorSystem("handler-system"))
implicit val ec = controllerComponents.executionContext
```

then in order to parse incoming POST request like :

```
   if(request.method == "POST") {
      for {
        parsedBody <- parsers.json.apply(request).run
        response <- parsedBody match {
          case Left(value) => //failed to parse body as json
          case Right(json) => //here goes you logic of body handling
        }
      } yield response
    }
```

Comment: i tried and doesn't work... i edited. Maybe I'm doing something wrong....